# I can not download PDF files from links generated from a javascript function with python 3.6.0 + selenium 3.4.3

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, download, screen-scraping

The URL is:[site](http://dje.trf2.jus.br/DJE/Paginas/Externas/inicial.aspx)

By using selenium with Firefox 47.0.2 binary and python 3.6.0, from this page I click on “Pesquisar” button and in the next page I fill in the form with tha date range (format d/m/y) and click again on the new “Pesquisar” button, then I get a list of PDF documents and I want to download them.

When I  print the page_source, I can see the links generated, but I don’t understand why selenium can’t locate those links.

The simplified code is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
from calendar import monthrange
import time


driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, firefox_binary=binary, capabilities=capabilities)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

months = range(1, 13)
limits = monthrange(2017, 8)

#num_docs = limites[1]-limites[0]

date_input_begin = '{num:0{width}}'.format(num=limits[0], width=2) + '08' + '2017'
date_input_end = '{num:0{width}}'.format(num=limits[1], width=2) + '08' + '2017'

today = datetime.now().date()
date = today

date = date - timedelta(24)

driver.get("http://dje.trf2.jus.br/DJE/Paginas/Externas/inicial.aspx")

driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ctrInicial_btnPesquisar").click()

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ctrFiltraPesquisaDocumentos_btnFiltrar"]')))

select1 = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ctrFiltraPesquisaDocumentos_ddlAreaJudicial"))
select1.select_by_index(3)

select2 = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ctrFiltraPesquisaDocumentos_ddlRegistrosPaginas"))
select2.select_by_index(6)

element_date_begin = driver.find_element_by_id(
    'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ctrFiltraPesquisaDocumentos_tbxDataInicial')
element_date_begin.clear()
element_date_begin.send_keys(date_input_begin)

element_date_end = driver.find_element_by_id(
    'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ctrFiltraPesquisaDocumentos_tbxDataFinal')
element_date_end.clear()
element_date_end.send_keys(date_input_end)

driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ctrFiltraPesquisaDocumentos_btnFiltrar').submit()

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ctrFiltraPesquisaDocumentos_btnFiltrar')))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ctrFiltraPesquisaDocumentos_btnFiltrar')))

time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_id('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ctrFiltraPesquisaDocumentos_btnFiltrar').click()

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ctrListaDiarios_udtVisualizaAdmRj_lblNomeCaderno"]')))

driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ctrListaDiarios_udtVisualizaAdmRj_grvCadernos_ct102_lnkData"]').click()
```

But when I look for the links by ID or XPATH, I get the following error:

> File "C:\Users\b2002032064079\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id=\"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_ctrListaDiarios_udtVisualizaAdmRj_grvCadernos_ct102_lnkData\"]"}

I’m a newbie at scraping and I’d be very thankful for any help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Which browser are you using?
2: Your site is slow. Maybe try giving more waiting time.
3: Is the xpath correct? I think that the problem is with the XPATH
try using XPath helper on chrome to check.

Comment: @biligung About the xpath, I have changed the last line of the code to:      `driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[7]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/a').click()`, in which the xpath now was gotten from firebug on firefox and it worked, thank you! About waiting time, I am still trying to solve it for downloading it iteratively.

Comment: If it helped give thumbs up :D  if you need to wait  -> there is some method uses javascript <> to check if page is reloaded but i dont know about download. It is handled by OS dialog so just set it manually.